# Tensor for expansion and tension

Tags: tensors, mathematical-modeling, classical-mechanics

I have a simple (and maybe silly...) question, but: How can I determine for an isotropic, linear elastic material the tensors for the expansion and the tension for $$\boldsymbol u(\boldsymbol x) = \gamma x_2 \boldsymbol e_1$$ where $\gamma \in \mathbb R$ ?

Comment: I'm interested in Cauchy's tensor  as well as in the tension tensor...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. In your answer, what's $\mu$ and where / how did you get the entries of the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

We usually don't speak of tension in the context of linear elastic bodies, but rather when speaking of wires, cables, chains, etc.

The present displacement field is a pure shear displacement field: only $u_{1,2} = \gamma$ is nonzero. Therefore, if we consider that $\lbrace\boldsymbol e_1, \boldsymbol e_2, \boldsymbol e_3\rbrace$ is an orthonormal basis of a Cartesian coordinate system, the infinitesimal strain tensor $\boldsymbol\varepsilon$ with coordinates $\varepsilon_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}(u_{i,j} + u_{j,i})$ has only two nonzero components out of the diagonal. Applying Hooke's law of [linear elasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_elasticity) $\sigma_{ij} = \lambda \delta_{ij}\varepsilon_{kk} + 2\mu\varepsilon_{ij}$ where $(\lambda,\mu)$ are the Lamé parameters, one gets the following components of the Cauchy stress tensor $\boldsymbol\sigma$:
$$
[σ_{ij}] = μγ
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
The traction vector $\boldsymbol t$ along the surface with normal $\boldsymbol n$ is given by $\boldsymbol t = \boldsymbol\sigma\cdot \boldsymbol n$.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for your answer! But what would you do if we had another u(x), let's say $u(x) = \delta x$, where $\delta \in \mathbb R$ ?

Comment: @DMan If $\boldsymbol u = \beta x_i \boldsymbol e_i$. Then $u_{i,j}= \beta \delta_{ij}$. In this case, the strain tensor is $\boldsymbol\varepsilon =\beta \boldsymbol I$, where $\boldsymbol I$ is the identity tensor, and $\boldsymbol\sigma = \beta (3\lambda + 2\mu) \boldsymbol I$.